# Angular checked property with radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

May be this was a simple problem i am trying to set `checked` attribute to radio buttons based on variable value

`$scope.art.is_copyright_protected = ($scope.art.is_copyright_protected==1)?true:false;`

```
 <div class="form-inline checkbox-wrap">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input name="is_copyright_protected"  ng-model="art.is_copyright_protected"     type="radio" id="radio11" >
        <label for="radio11">Yes</label>
     </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <input name="is_copyright_protected"  ng-model="art.is_copyright_protected"   type="radio" id="radio21"><label for="radio21">No</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

But the problem is radio button is never checked

Comment: you are missing the question mark in the if statment 
`$scope.art.is_copyright_protected =($scope.art.is_copyright_protected==1) ? true:false`

Comment: Actually its a typo occured while i am posting the question in the code it contains `?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) directive

> Binds the given expression to the value of the element.

```
<input ng-value="1" ng-model="art.is_copyright_protected" type="radio">
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.art = {
        is_copyright_protected: 0
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="form-inline checkbox-wrap">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input name="is_copyright_protected" ng-value="1" ng-model="art.is_copyright_protected" type="radio" id="radio11">
        <label for="radio11">Yes</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input name="is_copyright_protected" ng-value="0" ng-model="art.is_copyright_protected" type="radio" id="radio21"><label for="radio21">No</label>
      </fieldset>

      {{art.is_copyright_protected}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```